# Sending JSON object to WebMethod using AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, webmethod

I'm pulling in data from a HTML form and converting it to a JSON object to be sent to a WebMethod.

Right now it says that I'm getting a success response, but I'm not sure how to check that it is correctly being sent to the WebMethod. I've tried debugging in VS2015, but can't seem to get to the break point.

How can I test to see that I've set this all up correctly?

Here is my html:

```
 <form id="addForm" name="addForm">
     <input type="text"  name="playername" id="playername" placeholder="Player"/> 
     <input type="text" name="points" id="points" placeholder="Points" />
     <input type="text" name="steals" id="steals" placeholder="Steals" />
     <input type="text" name="blocks" id="blocks" placeholder="Blocks" /> 
     <input type="text" name="assists" id="assists" placeholder="Assists" />
     <input type="text" name="mpg" id="mpg" placeholder="MPG" /> 
     <input type="text" name="shotpct" id="shotpct" placeholder="Shot %" />
     <input type="text" name="threepct" id="3pct" placeholder="3 %" /> 
     <input type="button" value="add player" id="addbtn" name="addbtn" />
     </form>
```

My Ajax

```
$("#addbtn").click(function () {
                var form = JSON.stringify($("form").serializeArray());


                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "players.aspx/addRow",
                    data: form,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('failure');
                    }
                });
              });
```

and the web method where I'm trying to send the data

```
[WebMethod]
        public static void addRow(string form)
        {

            dynamic players = JObject.Parse(form);
        }
```

I'd like to what data is in players, if any (maybe getting a false positive from the AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
data: form,
```

with

```
data: "{form:" + form + "}",
```

and put a debugger inside the `WebMethod` using VS2015 to see what values are you getting for `addRow` method string variable `form`.

Comment: Like the red stop sign on the left side of the screen, correct? I've been doing that, but I haven't been able to hit the breakpoint. I put it on the line with the dynamic players. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: @hereswilson: [Check this out](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx). See how the debugger is show the values.

Comment: Also, make sure your ajax call url is actually. Open the browser console to see if you are getting any errors or not while making the ajax call onclick.

Comment: @palash I'm not getting any errors. How do I make that little box with all the info pop up? Also should the data be there after I click the button or after I click the button and dismiss the javascript alert?

Comment: Also am I using the right data type for that method? Cause how would C# handle a JSON object? object or string? something else?

Comment: Please check this out [_Debugging with VisualStudio 2015_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHnxx99DudI)

Comment: Ok, so I'm not hitting the break point so I'm not calling the webmethod correctly, but I'm not getting errors. What's going wrong?

Comment: Not sure about that might be a server side issue or something.

Comment: When I look at the response in the network tab of developer tools this is what it says `<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./addRow" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="2ZSteyOK6TXyd+n1jY76I+wzM5F1WbtCf7Yfvla06y6GGcMZPdgAFOAhDIK8fyC/Wt1AaTv7Qo8P/BbvhvwJw5DVInVVpUcQ+5POQXvZY+8=" />
</div>


</body>
</html>` Had to cut some stuff. Does that look correct?

Comment: This doesn't mean anything at all. Also, there is no text here at all to trace any issue.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something in my aspx file that doesn't connect it to the aspx.cs file? This is at the top:`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="players.aspx.cs" Inherits="nbaStats.players" %>`

Comment: replace your ajax code with this: `$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'players.aspx/addRow',
  data: "{form:" + form + "}",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('failure');
  }
});`

Comment: it failed. 500 Internal service error. "Message":"Type \u0027System.String\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList\u0026 convertedList)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain

Comment: (Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToType(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2

Comment: `2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: I thought that dataType was only used when something was being returned from the server?

Answer (score 0):

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class players : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void addRow(Player player)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        //dynamic players = JObject.Parse(form);
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string playername { get; set; }
    public string points { get; set; }
    public string steals { get; set; }
    public string blocks { get; set; }
    public string assists { get; set; }
    public string mpg { get; set; }
    public string shotpct { get; set; }
    public string _3pct { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#addbtn").click(function () {
                var player =
                    {
                        "playername": $("#playername").val(),
                        "points": $("#points").val(),
                        "steals": $("#steals").val(),
                        "blocks": $("#blocks").val(),
                        "assists": $("#assists").val(),
                        "mpg": $("#mpg").val(),
                        "shotpct": $("#shotpct").val(),
                        "_3pct": $("#3pct").val(),
                    };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "players.aspx/addRow",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ player: player }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function (errordata) {
                        alert('failure');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="addForm" name="addForm">
        <input type="text" name="playername" id="playername" placeholder="Player" />
        <input type="text" name="points" id="points" placeholder="Points" />
        <input type="text" name="steals" id="steals" placeholder="Steals" />
        <input type="text" name="blocks" id="blocks" placeholder="Blocks" />
        <input type="text" name="assists" id="assists" placeholder="Assists" />
        <input type="text" name="mpg" id="mpg" placeholder="MPG" />
        <input type="text" name="shotpct" id="shotpct" placeholder="Shot %" />
        <input type="text" name="threepct" id="3pct" placeholder="3 %" />
        <input type="button" value="add player" id="addbtn" name="addbtn" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: So I need to put that code on the .aspx page and not the html page?  I'm a little confused by that.